# Scale colour legend

Tags: r, plot, legend, legend-properties

can someone help to change the legend of this graphic to a continuous colour legend, like the legend in the second image.

```
library(demography)

plot.demogdata(portugal,series='male')   
legend("bottomright",legend=unique(portugal$year),
  col=rainbow(length(portugal$year)*1.25), ncol=5, pch=19, 
  title="Year", cex=0.5)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lower graph was produced with ggplot2. You can easily make the upper graph with ggplot2 and will get a continuous colour scale automatically.

Comment: How do you derive the object `portugal`? Without this we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Not really easy using base plot. Hints : you should prepare the legend region using `layout` and then use `image` and `axis`. As already mentioned Easier here to use some higher plot style.(ggplot2/lattice)

Comment: portugal is demogdata 
portugal<-hmd.mx("PRT",-,-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Not hi-tech, but works well for your need and does not require extra packages.
Copy & paste to R console to see how it works.

```
# not using layout function

# colors
n <- 1:50
col <- rainbow(length(n))

# expanding right margin 
par(mar=c(5,4,4,8),xpd=T)

# simulating any graph
plot(n,n*2,type='n',ylab="fun(x,n)")

# making DYI scale and legend
# scale
x <- rep(par('usr')[2]*1.1,length(n)+1)
y <- seq(f=par('usr')[3],t=par('usr')[4],length.out=length(n)+1)
nul <- sapply(n,FUN=function(n,col,x,y,...){lines(x=x[c(n,n+1)],y=y[c(n,n+1)],col=col[n],...)},lwd=30,lend="butt",col=col,x=x,y=y)
# labels
ty <- y[n]+diff(y)/2
tx <- rep(par('usr')[2]*1.25,length(n))
t <- paste("Lab",n)
ti <- pretty(n)
text(x=tx[ti],y=ty[ti],t[ti])
```

Comment: when I run the instruction plot(n,n*2,type='n',ylab="fun(x,n)") the plot is clear.

Comment: @user2898085 yes, that is because my code is just example, if you want to use it in your case, you have to adjust the code to your needs, I have old R version, no chance to install the package you are using, so I helped myself with epty plot.